# calculate limit O(n^k)

Tags: limits

The question is as follows:

if $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^k} < \infty$, then $f(n) = O(n^k)$, $n \longrightarrow \infty$

$f(n) = \frac{(n+1)(n^2+n+1)}{n}$

Calculate the smallest number of $k$ for which $f(n) = O(n^k)$

I don't know where I should start. Should I substitute $f(n)$ in the limit? And what should I do next?

Edit: I also need to calculate k for $f(n) = \frac{(n^2+1)\ln(n)}{n}$. Any idea how I could do that?

Answer (score 2):

As $f(n) = \frac{(n+1)(n^2+n+1)}{n} \sim n^2$, then for boundedness of $\frac{f(n)}{n^k}$ we need at least $k=2$.

For $f(n) = \frac{(n^2+1)\ln(n)}{n} \sim n\ln n$ i.e. $\frac{f(n)}{n^k} \sim \frac{\ln(n)}{n^{k-1}}$. If we need $k \in \Bbb{N}$, then again  $k=2$ at least.

Comment: If $k$ is not limited to natural numbers, then for the second example, you need to have $ k > 1$.  Thus there is no least real value of $k$ for which $f(n) = O(n^k)$.

Comment: @WA Don. Of course. That's why I emphasized case for natural $k$, where smallest exist.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(n)}{n^k}&=\frac{n^{3}+2n^2+2n+1}{n^{k+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{n^{k-2}}+\frac{2}{n^{k-1}}+\frac{2}{n^{k}}++\frac{1}{n^{k+1}}
\end{align*}
Observe that if $k<2$, then the first term will go to $\infty$. So you want $k\geq 2$. Now see if other terms behave nicely too.

Comment: For $k \geq 2 $, the other terms will become 0 eventually, because of the division by $\infty$. So the answer would be k = 2?